# Dispose function of user control not calling from BeginInvoke Method in c# winforms

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have one Main Form and on this Main Form I am adding one user control like below.

```
objCustomer = new Customer();
objCustomer.Top = this.Top;
objCustomer.Left = this.Left;
this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { this.Controls.Add(objCustomer); });
```

Now, on some event I have to unload this control and load other control.

```
if (objCustomer != null)
{
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { this.Controls.Remove(objCustomer); });
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { objCustomer.Dispose(); });
}
objEmployee = new Employee();
objEmployee.Top = this.Top;
objEmployee.Left = this.Left;

this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { this.Controls.Add(objEmployee); });
```

Now, on Customer `Dispose` function I have some routine are calling for logoff from other system.

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            Common.Log.LogEvent("Customer", "DisposedCall");
            LogOffServer();

            components.Dispose();

        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

I believe this Dispose event is not calling.

Please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that last `Dispose()` method is for your Form, if your conditional block is not being executed it is because all controls on a Winform are disposed before the Form's `Dispose()` method is called.  This means that `components != null` is false (because all `components` are already disposed) and the condition evaluates to false.

[Winform Event Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d.aspx)

Comment: the Dispose method is for UserControl. Let me check about this condition.